# Adding a UISegmentedControl to UISearchBar instead of Scope Buttons

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisegmentedcontrol

I'd like to add scope buttons below my UISearchBar. However I cannot change the tint color of the built in scope buttons.

Instead, I added a UISegmentedControl to my tableViewHeader. This works well enough, but it only shows when I am *not* typing into the UISearchbar. Not very convenient.

When I enter text into the UISearchBar, the table and segmented controls become hidden by the "no results shown" semi-opaque black layer. Once results start showing my segmented control disappears altogether, and only cells with results show.

I want to make the segmented control clickable during text entry into the search bar.

Do you know of any way to do the following?

1. make UISegmentedControl move with UISearchBar when text is being entered, or
2. show UISegmentedControl whilst search results are displayed on the UITableView

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try

```
@implementation UISearchBar (subviewAccess)
- (UISegmentedControl *)scopeBar {
  for (UIView *v in [self subviews]) {
    if ([v isKindOfClass:[UISegmentedControl class]])
      return v;
  }

  return nil;
}
```

@end

to get hold of the segmented control you want, and tint it from there
(it's currently at index 0, but that's definitely not for sure)

there is no "private API" being used, so apple should be okay with it,
but note if they changed their view layout (unlikely), this could break,
which would have the side effect of your tint disappearing, you should
access the rest of its state through the standard search bar APIs

Comment: Hi @bshirley, thanks however I already tried it. This seems to change the scope buttons into a normal UISegmentedControl but the height is out of whack. I also tried accessing each UISegment individually, but even though it responds to the setTintColor method, the color does not change. Any ideas?

Comment: there is additional tinting support for lots of components in iOS 5, if that's any consolation